# Moving files on the server side using webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I am working on a requirement that has the following logic. code is in C# and .NET CF 3.5

1. Upload some files from a mobile device to a web server.
2. when the upload is successful, the file is moved to an archived folder on the mobile device.
3. Download some files from the server to the mobile device.
4. When the download is successful, the file has to be moved to an archived folder on the server side in order so as not to download the same file again.

Wrote a web service (asmx) to handle this operation. The uploading and downloading works fine.

The webservice uses the function FileInfo.MoveTo() to move the file from the downloaded folder to the archives on the web server.

This works locally fine (when the webservice and the client calling the webservice are hosted on the same machine) but when deployed to a server, I get this message "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

I have given the necessary permissions to the IIS account on the server side. I would like to know if that can be achieved at all from the mobile device or is there any other way to invoke that call on the mobile device. I need to execute this method immediately after the file is downloaded.

Sample code is attached.

```
fileEntriesD = SomeWebService.FilesList();

        string[] extractedFiles = fileEntriesD.Split(',');

        foreach (string fileName in extractedFiles)
        {
            //dothe file downloading
            //code comes here.......   
        }

        //move the file on the server once all the files are downloaded

        foreach (string DumpfileName in extractedFiles)
        {
          //after the download is complete move the file to the archived folder
          string MoveFileOnServerStatus;
          MoveFileOnServerStatus = SomeWebService.MoveFileToArchive(DumpfileName);
          MessageBox.Show(MoveFileOnServerStatus);
        }
```

code for the WebMethod for MoveFileToArchive(DumpfileName)

```
   [WebMethod(Description="move the file to the archive location")]
   public string MoveFileToArchive(string fileArchiveName)
   {
        try
        {
            string SerPathD = GetLocationOfFiles + "\\" + "ArchivedDispatchedFiles";

            FileInfo MFTA = new FileInfo(SerPathD + "\\" + fileArchiveName);

            MFTA.MoveTo(SerPathD + "\\" + fileArchiveName);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            //if there is any error then return the error message.
               return ex.Message.ToString();
        }

            //if the moving was successful then return 1 to the client.
            return "1";
   }
```

Comment: when you are getting this condition, have you tried to do the move manually in the console or explorer to see if you get the same results?  also, can i ask how they are being saved initially?  (e.g. File.WriteAllBytes() or whatever)

Comment: Have you tried moving the file first and then doing the download?

Comment: I am using FileStream to read the file and then convert the stream to bytes. And see the code for the webservice. I return the error if there is any error or 1 if it is successful. I always get the error as "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

Comment: @m. Rajesh, your code seems to move the file to the same path. Should't you have a new location in `MoveTo` call?

Comment: Vinay: Yeah it is a typing error but this is to show an example and not the actual code. The main point is to show that the File.MoveTo always returns an error instead of success.

Comment: @Chuck Savage: I want the file to be archived only if the download was successful. Since I am downloading it from a mobile device there are chances that the download may not be successful every time. So that is out of the question for now.

Comment: You should show your download code - but anyway, your download code should probably be a class instance with IDisposable that wraps the download code, you then call it with a using statement that then free's up any resources that are touching the file in the `Dispose()` method when the download completes.